# Determine necessary and sufficient conditions on $x, N$ so that the following holds: for any $a, b$, if $ax ≡ bx \pmod N$, then $a ≡ b\pmod N$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Been working on it for a couple of hours with no success. My intuition tells me that it has to do something about $\gcd(n,x) = 1$
I have managed to prove that if $\gcd(x,n) = 1$ the claim holds, now I try to prove the other way around.
Any hint or a solution will help. thanks!

Comment: The condition $\gcd(x,n)=1$ is indeed a sufficient condition, since it means $x$ is a unit mod. $n$, but it is not  necessary. You have the same conclusion $(a\equiv b \mod n$) if $x$ is a non-zero divisor modulo $n$, which is a more complex problem.

Comment: What do you think of my solution @Bernard?

Comment: The implication is equivalent to the statement that the map $\, c\mapsto  cx\,$ is $1$-$1$ modulo $N$ (i.e. $\,x\,$ is *cancellable*), which is equivalent to $\,\gcd(x,N)=1\, $ by the well-known Theorem in the dupe. Btw, $x$ is not good  notation for a constant. Better notation would be $\ ax\equiv ay\Rightarrow\,x\equiv y\,$ for all $\,x,y\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, this holds if and only if $\gcd(n, x) =1$.

So, as you've already proved the first part, let's show the second one.

Assume for all $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}, ax\equiv bx \mod n \implies a \equiv b \mod n$.

Let $d := \gcd(x, n)$ and $(x', n') := (\frac{x}{d}, \frac{n}{d}) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$.

Take $(a, b) = (n', 0)$. One has $xn' = x'n'd = x'n \equiv 0 = x 0 \mod n$.

Then one should have $n' \equiv 0 \mod n$, which means $n | n'$. As one also has $n' | n$, this implies $|n'| = |n|$ thus $d = \gcd(n, x) = 1$.

Comment: Thanks A lot!!
I would also add that (n/d) <= n and (n/d) | n thus d = 1

Comment: Yeah, that also works @alon1230